# I don't see nobody Vs. I can't see nobody Vs. I see nobody

Tags: phrase-choice

If I come to my class and I see that I'm the only one there, then what is the way to say it out of the following three?

> I'm at the class and I see nobody
>
> I'm at the class I **don't** see nobody
>
> I'm at the class I **can't** see nobody

Comment: Would you please add more context? Are you being asked about the class situation? Without any context, I would say, "I am in the class and no one is here".

Comment: Thank you. I know that I have other choices, but I asked about these 3 choices. The class is only example. It maybe anywhere when some people should meet together etc.

Answer (score 4):

A native speaker would not be likely to say "I'm at the class."  Perhaps "I'm in class" or "I'm in the classroom."

For the second clause, many native speakers would say either the second or third option, but they are colloquial and frowned on in formal speech and writing.

The first option is formally correct, but does not sound idiomatic.  It could be old fashioned, foreign, or just stilted.

More idiomatic options include

- I don't see anybody
- I don't see anyone
- I can't see anybody
- I can't see anyone

The distinction between "don't" and "can't" is small enough that either is acceptable in most cases.  Because "can't see anyone" means that one is unable to see any people, it could imply that there is some impediment to vision, such as darkness or a fog, though it's also possible that the inability to see people arises from a lack of people to be seen.  On the other hand, "don't" is a bit more matter of fact.  If the intention is simply to imply that nobody else is there, it might be a slightly better choice.